# Связь многие ко многим Code-First

Tags: c#, codefirst

Всем привет друзья. Реализую связь через промежуточную таблица.

Таблица Event и Car имеют результирующую таблицу Result

Вроде бы все работает да это и странно, подскажите друзья. Я правильно реализовал связь?

```
  using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BaseModels
{
    public class BaseModelInfo
    {
       [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }


    public class User : BaseModelInfo
    {   
        //Много
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    }

    public class Car : BaseModelInfo
    {
        //одын
        public virtual User Users { get; set; }
        public virtual Car Cars { get; set; }

        public virtual Result Results { get; set; }

        //public int? ResultId { get; set; }  
        //***
        //***
        //public int User_id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
       

    }

    public class Event :BaseModelInfo
    {
        public DateTime DateE { get; set; }
        //public DateTime DateEvent { get; set; }
        //public int Car_id { get; set; }
        //
        // public int? ResultId { get; set; }
        public virtual Result Results { get; set; }
        
       // public int? CarId { get; set; }
        public virtual Car Cars { get; set; }

    }



    public class Result : BaseModelInfo
    {   
        public DateTime DateR { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }    


}
```

Comment: Я не увидел тут связи многие-ко-многим. Почитайте про этот вид связи, поглядите на ваши результирующие таблицы.

Comment: свое знакомство с Entity Framework я начал с [метанита](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/), так же рекомендую данный [туториал](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx)

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF.